# Why should I set default value of foreign key, django

Tags: python, django

For example, we have this code:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Bar(models.Model):
    b = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    a = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

And when I run makemigrations, i see that I need set default of a(Bar)
Can anyone explain me, why should I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that you already have some data in your database (or you have made a migration before adding the `ForeignKey` field). In order for the migration to work you will need to "tell" Django what data should be in the `a` column of the `Bar` table for rows that already exist.

Either delete your whole database/earlier migrations, or provide a default value of your choice:

```
a = models.ForeignKey(Foo, default=None) # or any other default value
```

Comment: Makemigrations doesn't look at what is already in your database, as the created migrations should also be able to work if there is none yet.

Comment: It doesn't directly look at the db, but if there is already a migration before adding the `ForeignKey` field it will require a default value. I will rephrase my answer to reflect that.